# Problems building hiphop on Ubuntu 11.10 (Hiphop)

Tags: php, hiphop

when I come to hiphop-php directory and
run cmake .
I get the following errors:

> -- Could NOT find LIBINOTIFY (missing:  LIBINOTIFY_LIBRARY LIBINOTIFY_INCLUDE_DIR)
>
> CMake Error at CMake/FindLibunwind.cmake:19 (message):
>
> libunwind.h found without matching unwind.h
>
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
>
> CMake/HPHPFindLibs.cmake:38 (find_package)
>
> CMake/HPHPSetup.cmake:46 (include)
>
> src/CMakeLists.txt:18 (include)

I don't know how to install the LIBINOTIFY

I'm runing on linux mint 12,that's based on ubuntu 11.10

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Definitely one for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/), voting to move

Comment: @DaveRandom Indeed. Following suit. The question poser will get a much better reply from the folks over there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install libunwind:

https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/issues/563

This is annoyingly NOT in the Ubuntu setup directions. You may run into some issues when you `make` however, so follow these too:

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.unwind.devel/1133

Comment: @PaulTarjan: I later opened an issue and updated the wiki. I see you've been busy closing issues and listening to feedback! :)